# Por que no puedo imprimir el resultado de una consulta en angular 6?

Tags: json, angular, angular5

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
getReport(id_reporte: string, destino: number, departamento: string,
      afiliacion: string, tipo_servicio: string, canal: string,
      fechai: string, fechaf: string, por: string): Observable <Afiliados[]> {

  return this.http.post<Afiliados[]>(
    this.url, JSON.stringify(
    {
      'id_reporte': id_reporte,
      'destino': destino
    }),
    httpOptions);
}
```

Mi interface que recibo:

```
export interface Afiliados {
    Nombre: string, 
    Email: string
}
```

Mi invocacion del metodo:

```
this.RAfiliados.getReport(this.id , 2, '' , '' , '' , '' , '20170616' , '20180719' , '' )
    .subscribe(data => this.ARAfiliados = data);
```

A la hora de recorrer el arreglo:

```
<tr *ngFor="let afiliados of ARAfiliados">
    <td>{{afiliados.Nombre}}</td><td>{{afiliados.Email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Mi respuesta json:

```
        [
            {
                "nombre": " ejemplo ",
                "email": "ejemplo@ejemplo.com "
            },
            {
                "nombre": " ejemplo ",
                "email": "ejemplo2@ejemplo2.COM "
            }
        ]
```

Pero a la hora de ver el resultado me mustra el tamaño total de mi respuesta pero no sepinta la informacion en la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas buscando por el atributo Nombre siendo que recibes nombre (todo en minúsculas), corrigiendo eso debería funcionar correctamente.
Puedes corregir en el servidor (enviando Nombre e Email) o en el frontend (usando nombre e email en minusculas)

Comment: SI, ahora mismo que estaba preguntando me di cuenta del error, que tonteria. Gracias